# Can I use R to do a buffer inside polygons (shrink polygons / "negative" buffer)?

Tags: r, buffer

I want to use R (working with SpatialPolygons) to create a buffer **inside** my polygons - or actually shrink them by a value; ideally only if something is left after shrinking.

The buffer function I know (e.g. `raster::buffer`) allows only positive values (creating a buffer around features).

I thought of a workaround: Converting polygon to polylines (outline), creating buffer, subtracting buffer from original polygon. But that seems kind of dirty. I am wondering whether there is a package / function I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sf package

```
# read shapefile (or other formats)
shpA <- read_sf("some_shapefile.shp")
# or from sp spatial structure
shpA <- st_as_sf(someSpatialPolygons)

# buffer size, here 10 units of shpA coordinates inward
# (better if projected coordinate system)
buffer_size <- (-10)

# compute buffered polygons
shpA_buffered <- st_buffer(shpA, buffer_size) 

# remove degenerate polygons
shpA_remaining <- shpA_buffered[!st_is_empty(shpA_buffered),]
```

As per OP request I designed a function that will try to shrink input polygons and in case of degeneration return original polygons.

```
# NB size is given as a positive value
shrinkIfPossible <- function(sf, size) {
  # compute inward buffer
  sg <- st_buffer(st_geometry(sf), -size)
  
  # update geometry only if polygon is not degenerate
  st_geometry(sf)[!st_is_empty(sg)] = sg[!st_is_empty(sg)]
   
  # return updated dataset
  return(sf)
}

shp_buffered <- shrinkIfPossible(shpA, 10)
```

Comment: cool. can I do a "left join" on the sf datastructure of `shpA_remaining` and `shpA_buffered`, so that I don't loose the "degenerate" polygons but keep them unchanged (=unbuffered)

Comment: @Honeybear You surely can do so or rbind ShpA and Shp_buffered filtered according to st_is_empty. I packaged this process in an easier to use function that could be of interest for others

Comment: wish I could upvote twice. Thank you!

Comment: rather than reinjecting original polygons to replace degenerate polygons, I suggest only injecting non-degenerate polygons (1 line of code instead of 3):  `st_geometry(sf)[!st_is_empty(sg)] = sg[!st_is_empty(sg)]` (I put this in an edit that needs approval)

Comment: Of course ! Quick hacks need revisions :-) Thanks @Honeybear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a function that allows negative buffering: `rgeos::gBuffer()`

A code example:

```
library(rgeos)

# use readOGR() or shapefile() to read SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from .shp file
shpA = shapefile(file.path(PATH_DATA, 'sample_test_A.shp')) # or:
shpA = readOGR(file.path(PATH_DATA, 'sample_test_A.shp'))

# plot original polygon
plot(shpA, col='blue')

# create and plot shrinked polygon
shpA_buffered = gBuffer(shpA, width=-30)
plot(shpA_buffered, add = T, col='red')
```

This however will return "empty" polygons if the shrinkage is too big. Maybe someone has an answer for that?